# Spring Webservice Client - Empty soapAction returning in response "Message part Request was not recognized"

Tags: java, spring, soap, soap-client, spring-ws

I am using spring webservices for consuming a service. I am following this article https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/, I have created a client by extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport` and using that to invoke the service.

The first doubt I have is that I haven't generated any java classes from wsdl (other than jaxb objects for the types mentioned in wsdl). Don't I have to generate the stub (endpoint) classes on the client side? If not, then how does spring know which operation to be invoked as my wsdl has multiple operations?

Here is my code

```
public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Object callWebService(String url, Object request){
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this is the package name specified in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.howtodoinjava.schemas.school");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://www.example.com/ExampleServiceBean");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

The second issue is that on executing above code I am getting following error message, can someone please help me how to fix it:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Message part Request was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:506)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:424)
```

I might be a missing a very basic thing as I am using spring webservices for the first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to get it working with Jax-WS, apparently spring webservices do not work if soapAction is empty in WSDL.